# Laravel eloquent add custom query elements

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

So I am having some trouble with size and server requests. So I am trying to get a minified version of a row from eloquent. So for example here is my query call

```
$user = User::where('email', '=', 'example@test.com')->first();
```

This works but returns a ton of information. Stuff that I do not need, relations, observables, dates, guarded status, fillable AND every single column. This is expected so If I want to get first and last name and email. I could do something like this

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('firstname','lastname', 'email')->get();
```

And this would work, except I don't want to type that every single time I wanna do this. Is it possible for me to setup somewhere in eloquent or in my model so that I can do

```
$user = User::where('email', '=', 'example@test.com')->min()->first();
```

Simply add a custom function called min() that only grabs those three values. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do it if you declare a method in your `User` model like this:

```
// User.php
public function scopeMin($query)
{
    return $query->select('firstname','lastname', 'email');
}
```

Then you can use it like this (To get only `'firstname','lastname', 'email'`):

```
$user = User::where('email', '=', 'example@test.com')->min()->first();
```

Read about [Query Scope](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes) on the documentation.

Comment: Perfect! this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Only I wouldn't call it `min`, since there's already a method on the builder `min()`. And it will still return full object, just a few less fields.

Answer (score 4):

You can limit the columns by passing an array in the first() method.

```
$user = User::where('email', '=', 'example@test.com')->first(['firstname','lastname', 'email']);
```

Comment: This is not what the `OP` asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the $hidden array at your model, with the columns that you don't want to appear.